# Equivalence and Presupposition

Tags: logic

This is a very basic question about the relationship between presupposition and implication. The question is as follows: Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three propositions and let $A\Leftrightarrow B$, do we have ($\star$)? $$\textrm{$A$ presupposes $C$ iff $B$ presupposes $C$}\quad\quad\quad(\star)$$ In other words, if two propositions are logically equivalent, must they carry the same presuppositions?

Comment: What is "presupposition" ? That A implies B?

Comment: No, A implies B is simply an implication, not a presupposition. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presupposition/ for an intro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The definition of presupposition is

$$A \text{ presupposes } C \text{ iff } A \vDash C \text{ and } \neg A \vDash C \text{ and } \nvDash C$$

That is, $A$ presupposes $C$ iff $C$ follows both from $A$ and its negation but $C$ is not tautological.

If $A \Leftrightarrow B$, then $\neg A \Leftrightarrow \neg B$. So

$\begin{align*}
& A \text{ presupposes } C \\
\text{ iff } & A \vDash C \text{ and } \neg A \vDash C \\
\text{ iff } & B \vDash C \text{ and } \neg B \vDash C \\
\text{ iff } & B \text{ presupposes } C
\end{align*}$

So $\textrm{$A$ presupposes $C$ iff $B$ presupposes $C$}$.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know if this generalizes. Consider this simple example: Mary is happy iff she receives the first prize from the competition. Let $A$ stands for "Mary is happy'' and $B$ for "she receives the first prize from the competition". Clearly, $B$ presupposes that there is such a competition. But this is not presupposed by $A$, right?

Comment: What you have in your example is a biconditional ($\leftrightarrow$), not logical equivalence ($\Leftrightarrow$). These are two different things. Logical equivalence means that $A$ and $B$ have the same truth values in *all* conveivable situations. But what is said in the competition example is just that the two states of affairs coincide in *this particular* situation. This doesn't, however, make the $A$ and $B$ sentences equivalent, i.e. identical in meaning: We can, in principle, easily think of a situation where Mary is unhappy despite having won the competition.

Comment: So the transitivity is not applicable here because your example is not one of logical equivalence. Indeed, as you notice, it fails here; the argument doesn't work for biconditional claims.

Comment: Ah, okay. I see the difference. Thanks a lot!